# Python - Only printing 'PRINT'

Tags: python

I am trying to make my own basic programming language. I have the following code in my `smrlang.py` file

```
from sys import *

tokens = []

def open_file(filename):
    data = open(filename, "r").read()
    return data

def smr(filecontents):
    tok = ""
    state = 0
    string = ""
    filecontents = list(filecontents)
    for char in filecontents:
        tok += char
        if tok == " ":
            if state == 0:
                tok = ""
            else:
                tok = " "
        elif tok == "PRINT":
            tokens.append("PRINT")
            tok = ""
        elif tok == "\"":
            if state == 0:
                state = 1
            elif state == 1:
                print("STRING")
                string = ""
                state = 0
        elif state == 1:
            string += tok
    print(tokens)
def run():
    data = open_file(argv[1])
    smr(data)
run()
```

And I have this in my `one.smr` file:

```
PRINT "HELLO WORLD"
```

The output should be something like `PRINT STRING`, but when I use the command `python3 smrlang.py one.smr`, the output is just `PRINT`. I am using Python 3

Comment: Use a debugger or add more debugging print statement to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging it in the head, I found the problem:

```
elif state == 1:
    string += tok
```

You don't reset the token here. It will be `aababcabcd` instead of `abcd` and recognizing `\` won't work (as it will be `aababcabcd\`).

This also causes the token to just be everything and it will never print.

Try changing it to:

```
elif state == 1:
    string += tok
    tok = ""
```

Output after fix:

```
> py -3 temp.py temp.txt
STRING
['PRINT']
```